# Python: Got an Error Statement for "local variable 'idx' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python

```py
def removeNonAlpha(myString, key):
      from string import ascii_lowercase
      alphabet = ascii_lowercase + ' '
      myString = myString.lower()
      cipherText = ' '
      for ch in myString:
        if ch == 1 or ch == 2 or ch == 3 or ch == 4 or ch == 5 or ch == 6 or ch == 7 or ch == 8 or ch == 9 :
          idx = alphabet.find(ch)
        cipherText = cipherText + key[idx] 
      return cipherText
```

Running my script with:

```py
removeNonAlpha('My favorite Cat was named Patches', alphabet)
```

returns the following error

```
          7     if ch == 1 or ch == 2 or ch == 3 or ch == 4 or ch == 5 or ch == 6 or ch == 7 or ch == 8 or ch == 9 :
          8       idx = alphabet.find(idx)
    ----> 9     cipherText = cipherText + key[idx]
         10   return cipherText

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'idx' referenced before assignment
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Think about what happens when your `if` condition is false on the first iteration, then you *don't assign anything to `idx`*

Comment: Note also, if `myString` is a `str`, then `ch` will *never* equal an `int` as you are testing in your condition

Comment: See [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 2):

It means you tried to use the variable 'idx' before creating. 'idx' is only created inside the if, but the line that uses 'idx' is outside the 'if' statement, so it runs even when the 'if' fails

Answer (score 0):

just change the function to following:

```
def removeNonAlpha(myString, key):
  from string import ascii_lowercase
  alphabet = ascii_lowercase + ' '
  myString = myString.lower()
  cipherText = ' '
  for ch in myString:
    if ch == 1 or ch == 2 or ch == 3 or ch == 4 or ch == 5 or ch == 6 or ch == 7 or ch == 8 or ch == 9 :
      idx = alphabet.find(ch)
      cipherText = cipherText + key[idx] #edits
  return cipherText
```

Answer (score 0):

its because your idx is not getting initialised if the condition does not pass, moreover there are some changes you could make with regards to that massive conditional, try this:

```py
def removeNonAlpha(myString, key):
      from string import ascii_lowercase
      alphabet = ascii_lowercase + ' '
      myString = myString.lower()
      cipherText = ' '
      for ch in myString:
        idx = #make some default value 
        if ch in ['123456789']:
          idx = alphabet.find(ch)
        cipherText = cipherText + key[idx] 
      return cipherText
```

You have to initialise idx with some default value and maybe add a check if idx was found or not.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Completely changed my code but here's the working results:

```
`def removeNonAlpha(myString):
  from string import ascii_lowercase
  alphabet = ascii_lowercase + ' '
  myString = myString.lower()
  cipherText = ' '
  

  return myString


def getFreq(tuples): 
  return tuples[1]
  # this returns the second element of a tuple #
countDict = {}
with open('wells.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as wells:
  text = wells.read()
  for word in text.split():
    word = removeNonAlpha(word)
    if word in countDict:
      countDict[word] += 1
    else: 
      countDict[word] = 1


wordList = list(countDict.items())

wordList.sort(key = getFreq)

for wordTuple in wordList[-10:]:
  print(wordTuple)`
```